# Issue with singleclick and gestureHandling cooperative

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

So I have added a single click event listener to the map that adds a marker to the map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is it is getting fired when the user goes to swipe the map in mobile, but it doesn't swipe because the map is cooperative (needs to fingers to swipe). Is there something I can do to prevent that behavior while keeping the map cooperative. In the meantime I have made the map greedy. Thanks in advance!